# Oracle: Monitoring changes in v_$parameter

Tags: oracle

Long time user, first time "asker".

I am attempt to construct an Oracle procedure and/or trigger that will compare two tables with the MINUS operation and then insert any resulting rows into another table. I understand how to do the query in standard SQL, but I am having trouble coming up with an efficient way to do this using PL/SQL.

Admittedly, I am very new to Oracle and pretty green with SQL in general. This may be a silly way to go about accomplishing my goal, so allow me to explain what I am attempting to do.

I need to create some sort of alert that will be triggered when the **V_$PARAMETER** view is changed. Apparently triggers can not respond to changes to view but, instead, can only replace actions on views...which I do not wish to do. So, what I did was create a table that to mirror that view to essentially save it as a "snapshot".

```
create table mirror_v_$parameter as select * from v_$parameter;
```

Then, I attempted to make a procedure that would minus these two so that, whenever a change is made to **v_$parameter**, it will return the difference between the snapshot, **mirror_v_$parameter**. I trying to create a cursor with the command:

```
select * from v_$parameter minus select * from mirror_v_$parameter;
```

to be used inside a procedure, so that it could be used to fetch any returned rows and insert them into another table called **alerts_v_$parameter**. The intent being that, when something is added to the "alert" table, a trigger can be used to somehow (haven't gotten this far yet) notify my team that there has been a change to the **v_$parameter** table, and that they can refer to **alerts_v_$parameter** to see what has been change. I would use some kind of script to run this procedure at a regular interval. And maybe, some day down the line when I understand all this better, manipulate what goes into the **alerts_v_$parameter** table so that it provides better information such as specifically what column was changed, what was its previous value, etc.

Any advice or pointers?

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Any thoughts will be very appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  Database initialization parameters should not be a free fire zone.  So, if you need to be informed of changes to them, you need to get included in the loop when changes are agreed.

Comment: If you have random people changing system parameters, then you have bigger problems.  See this link - there may be alternatives http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tracking_auditing_changes_initialization_parameters.htm

Comment: Very true. Unfortunately, I work in a large organization where many people have access to change the system parameters. Despite the fact they should not be arbitrarily changed whenever, by whoever, it sometimes happens. It would be helpful to know when this has occurred so that time is not wasted tracking down issues this may have caused in the wrong places.

Comment: I was going to suggest triggering on the "real" table underneath the SYS.V_$PARAMETER view.  HOWEVER - there seems to be an infinite recursion here. The SYS.V_$PARAMETER view reads from an object named V$PARAMETER.  According to the DBA_OBJECTS view, V$PARAMETER is a synonym which refers to the V_$PARAMETER view.  Therefore, V_$PARAMETER references V$PARAMETER which references V_$PARAMETER which references V$PARAMETER which...(etc ad nauseum).  Say WHAT?!?

Comment: Thank you, OldProgrammer. That link looks like it will be very helpful.

Comment: That method from dba-oracle.com can only be used if you have licensed AWR, and therefore are on Enterprise Edition. If you are have not then you're not in compliance with your licensing conditions. Oracle tracks usage of licensed features internally so if the auditors come knocking they will catch you.

Comment: Agree with APC. What you're doing here is equivalent to installing a CCTV system on a bank safe that is never locked, so by the time you know something has changed it's already too late. Better to lock the door and limit who has access.

Comment: @BobJarvis It's unlikely that there's a "real" table in there. These values are read from pfiles or spfiles, so all that is held is a read-only representation in the instance memory. Apart from the likely problems of placing a trigger on a system table, which would probably invalidate support, it's therefore unlikely that there are any conventional modifications to that table through the SQL engine that a trigger could be invoked by.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - poo.  I'm just *sure* this is some sort of Da-Vinci-Code-Star-Chamber-New-World-Order-Manchurian-Candidate thing.  'Scuse me - gotta go to my PTCA (Paranoid Conspiracy Theorists Anonymous) meeting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a table based on the exact structure of v_$parameter with an additional timestamp column for "last_update", and periodically (via DBMS_Scheduler) merge into it any changes from the real v_$parameter table and capture the timestamp of any detected change.

You might also populate a history table at the same time, either using triggers on update of your table or with SQL.

PL/SQL is unlikely to be required, except as a procedural wrapper to the SQL code.

Examples of Merge are in the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: Thanks, David. I'm investigating this option now to see if it does the trick.